# Setup GitLab Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I need to set up a pipeline for a branch that will do the following,

- On push, it will trigger a pipeline (which happens as per GitLab)
- 1st Job to trigger a build (.net5) for the branch (new code pushed to the branch). If the build succeeds, it will begin the next job. However, I am to trigger build (MSBuild) on the runner location check out when the pipeline runs. But is there any way to directly run a build on the branch?
- If the above build fails, the push should be reverted on a branch. I applied git revert and reset commands, but it only gets used to the build location of the runner. I need to revert commit at the branch level.

Answer (score 0):

When GitLab starts a pipeline, it is a "detached HEAD" which basically means it creates a temporary branch that points to your specific commit. It does this because there might be a commit after it which the current build doesn't know about.

To get out of the detached head, you need to switch to the branch directly.

```
git checkout branch-name
```

To get the branch name, you find an appropriate [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) which works for your.

Once you have that, you need to get the latest version so you can revert. I usually needed the reset here to make things work.

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

From there, you can revert. Now, the CI process doesn't have write permissions, so you need to have a GitLab access token with write permissions, which means you have to set up a new origin or parent.

```
git remote add changes https://oauth2:$PUSH_GITLAB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/group-name/project-1
git push -f changes branch-name
```

Now... that said, this is probably **not what you want to do**. Since you said you were new to CI, I'm going to say I'm 99.99999% sure you don't want to go down this path because it only leaves to heartache and frustration.

The reason is the branch may have a second or additional commit. It could be you missed something at the last minute and threw up a new one, an automated process starts up, or just your typical race conditions. Reverting a commit means you either will blow up with those changes or you end up erasing every other commit as you have to force push to get it up.

This also means that this is a very fragile process and will break many times, usually at the worst times (when you have a rapid series of commits), and then you have to tell everyone to stop working while you fix it.

(A good sign is how much work you have to do to fight the CI process.)

Instead, I recommend you create a merge request (MR) against your branch and set up the rules to make sure *that* is valid before you merge it into your branch. That way, the process doesn't have to worry about future or past commits, it just says what you have in your merge request (which is another branch) can't be applied after merging it with `branch-name`.

In our team, we have many branches (`main`, `next`, `release/2.3.4`, `release/2.4.0`, etc.) and doing MRs against each one has worked out well. We do the merge requests against each of the release branches, and the CI process says it can merge and pass tests before it tries to commit, but then we can commit knowing that 98+% of the time, it will be fine.

And it doesn't require jumping through hoops.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Let me setup as you suggested and will revert on the same. Cheers Mate 